# Adding Particles in Unity, using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game with some obstacles collide eachother(Player and the enemy) and have their own Particle effects after having their collisions.
I am facing with a problem that occurs when I put a particle effect as child object of an obstacle. The effect that I put in doesn't work. And I know that happens because when the object gets destroyed, particles aswell but,
I tried to create a new Game Object in the Hierarchy called 'Particle Manager' to make it have a seperate way from the Player object itself. I created its own Script called 'ParticleManager':

I will share the script that I wrote for it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ParticleManager particleManager;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 10.0f;
    private float playerBorderYMax = 8.0f;
    private float playerBorderYMin = -6.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();   
        particleManager = GetComponent<ParticleManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MovePlayer();   
        DestroyOutOfBordersPlayer();
    }

    //Move the player
    void MovePlayer()
    {
        float verticalInputIndex = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * playerSpeed * verticalInputIndex * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    //Prevent player to fly up above the upper borders
    void DestroyOutOfBordersPlayer()
    {
        if(transform.position.y > playerBorderYMax || transform.position.y < playerBorderYMin)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            particleManager.explosionParticle.Play();
        }
    }
  
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Game Over!");
            Destroy(gameObject);
            particleManager.explosionParticle.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

In my ParticleManager Script I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ParticleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem explosionParticle;   
}
```

After all of these, when I get back to Unity, this error shows up:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerMovement.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collision) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:51)
UnityEngine.Physics:OnSceneContact(PhysicsScene, IntPtr, Int32)
```

And of course my particles don't work.
I try to creat some particle effects for the player when they collide with enemy. I was expecting the script that I wrote would work, but it didn't.

Comment: `particleManager = GetComponent<ParticleManager>();` - that looks for a component on the same gameobject. It will not access any other gameobjects in your scene. Did you check whether this line actually works as intended?

Comment: if the particles is a child of the object and you destroy it.. yes the particles go too